# microsoft cognitive services OCR not reading text

Tags: vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to read text from an image using Microsoft Cognitive Vision service. Sample of my request as below.

```
POST https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation =true HTTP/1.1
Host: centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <subscription key>

{"url":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G6br.png"}
```

But the result returns blank. If I use tesseract to read this data, I get 25178 as text as expected. I do not want to go with tesseract as I would have a dependency on tesseract installable as pre-requisite.

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here. 
Also, attaching original and scaled image (this one:

[image: awfe]
as well for reference.

---

Original:

[image: original]

---

Scaled:

[image: scaled]

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing something wrong: I tried with the link you provided and go nothing detected, like you.

Looks like the OCR capability is not good enough to detect this value